# Bijective continuous map between the same set (but different topologies) implies one topology is finer than the other

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: X \to X$ be a bijective continuous map where the set domain is equipped with topology $\tau_1$ and the range is equipped with a topology $\tau_2$. I have been given the task to show that this is enough to imply $\tau_2 \subset \tau_1$.

My (poor) attempt:

I want to exploit the fact that $f$ is continuous. So, let $U$ be some open
set in $\tau_2$, then through continuity, we know that $f^{-1}(U)$ is also open in $\tau_1$. So far this tells me that

if $U\in\tau_2$, then $f^{-1}(\tau_1)$

However, I want to show if $U\in\tau_2$, then $U\in\tau_1$ but I'm simply not seeing how I would show that.

Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image: question]

Comment: what you are trying to prove is false

Comment: In order for $U \in \tau_2 \implies U \in \tau_1$ to be true, $f$ would have to be assumed to be the identity function.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking as well @Dustan. Maybe that was why I got stuck :p. I have put the exact question in the post itself, can you take a look at it just in case I asked the question wrong ?

Comment: Yeah, the exercise is false if $h$ isn't assumed to be the identity.

Comment: alright thank you everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the topology $\tau_1$ on $\mathbb R$ with open sets $\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\},\mathbb R$

Consider the topology $\tau_2$ on $\mathbb R$ with open sets $\varnothing,\{0\},\mathbb R$

The bijective map $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x-1$ is continuous.

However $\tau_1$ does not contain $\tau_2$.